# Does "be over later" mean today or later in the week?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, time

Well texting someone yesterday. They stated,

> I will be over Later.

Does this imply they will be there later in the week? Or later that day?

Comment: It usually means "later in the day" (depending on time of day) but it is ambiguous, it just means "after now"...

Comment: As @Peter says. If it were not the same day, one would more likely say "tomorrow morning" or another date referencing word.

Comment: When I first visited Australia in the 80s, I found it odd that people would use "see you later" as a general purpose leaving phrase, even if there was no expectation that we'd see each other again that day.

Comment: @Colin do they have alligators in Australia, or is it crocodiles? 

Answer (score 1):

"**Later**" means *at a time in the near future; soon*.

So "**I will be over later**"  means "**I will be over in the near future (soon)**".

As **@Peter** commented this usually refers to **some time after now**.

Consider these expressions:

- Later!
- See you later!